# How to cite like this?

Tags: citing

I want to cite the research papers in the way given in the image.

[image]

I just want to cite like Hanneke [5] (article number). Till now using smart citation I am not able to do this.

Comment: If and how the output can be changed depends on the citation and bibliography package you are using as well as the style. Please show us a complete example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that tells us which packages you use. From the look of it you might be using `natbib` (with the default `authoryear` option) in which case it should be enough to load it with the `numbers` option and use `\citet` consistently. (From the screenshot I can't tell if you use `\cite` or `\citet`.)

Comment: To complete the thought I was implying in the parentheses at the end of my last comment (but the character limit did not allow me to finish), note that the `natbib` documentation recommends against using `\cite` and encourages you to use either `\citep` or `\citet` depending on the desired output. For backwards compatibility reasons the behaviour of `\cite` is different between `numbers` and `authoryear`, but the behaviour of `\citet` and `\citep` is consistent and if you will invariant under change of citation styles.

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate the above comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     citecolor    = blue
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{hanneke,
author = "Z. Hanneke",
title = "A very important title",
year = "2019",
publisher = "A very important Publishing House",
}
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~[\citenum{#1}]}
\begin{document}
\mycite{hanneke}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

will give

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but color how to change it and after clicking on the name. I am not landing into pdf.

Comment: Use the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @ Denis  I have used it as uspackage command , but not working.

Comment: @I_wil_break_wall See my edit.